# Writing power for a log

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to express `(\ln{(x)})^4` as `\ln^4{(x)}` but the power takes up too much space between ln and x. How should it be written?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I would just omit the inner parentheses, i.e., write `$(\ln x)^4$`. Do note that the macro `\ln` does *not* take a formal argument. Hence, `\ln x` and `\ln{x}` both produce the same output; I'd argue that `\ln x` involves no code clutter and hence is to preferred. About the space between `^4` and `x` in the output of `\ln^4 x`: That's entirely analogous to what's produced by `\sin^2 x` or `\cos^3\theta`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

Here is a (non-comprehensive) list of choices you have (bests are **4** and **1**) to correctly typeset what you want:

1. `(\ln x)^4` is correct but may seem *heavy* from a mathematical point of view. Thus you may prefer placing the power between the ln and the *x*.
2. `\ln^4 x` is what you suggested but it adds a big space after the 4 which makes it really weird for the reader.
3. `\ln^4(x)`. Here, the visual is more clear but a small thin extra space remains between the 4 and the parenthesis which is problematic from a typographic point of view.
4. `\lnn{4}{x}` where `\lnn` is defined by `\newcommand{\lnn}[2]{\ln^{#1}\mkern-1mu(#2)}`. The `x` and the `4` are arguments of the `\lnn` function (which may come in handy) and the visual is perfect. The only problem is that you had to define a new command.

### Code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lnn}[2]{\ln^{#1}\mkern-1mu(#2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \verb|$(\ln x)^4$| produces:
    
    $(\ln x)^4$
    \item \verb|$\ln^4 x$| produces:
    
    $\ln^4 x$
    \item \verb|$\ln^4(x)$| produces:
    
    $\ln^4(x)$
    \item \verb|$\lnn{4}{x}$| produces:
    
    $\lnn{4}{x}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: LaTeX output]

Edit: as @egreg specified in the comments, `\ln` does not take arguments since it's defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand\ln{\mathop{\operator@font ln}\nolimits}` so I updated my answer in light of it.

Comment: The command `\ln` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my answer

Comment: +1: BTW, there are still some `ln{x}` in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed the last ones.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the braces are superfluous and should be omitted. Now I list four different ways to typeset the thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$(\log x)^4$ is mathematically sound

$\log^4x$ isn't so sound

$(\log(x))^4$ is preferred by somebody

$\log^4(x)$ is not really good

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of `\showoutput` we can see the details of the typesetting.

#### First case

```
....\mathon
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x12.91669
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.....\kern0.13887
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -3.62892
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 4
....\mathoff
```

You can see that there are two spaces after the “g”: one is the italic correction, which is necessary because the letter somewhat extends right of its bounding box. The second one is the usual thin space.

With the dreaded `\ln` we'd get

```
....\mathon
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x8.33336
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -3.62892
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 4
....\mathoff
```

because there is no italic correction for the “n”.

#### Second case

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x12.91669
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.....\kern0.13887
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -4.47224
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 4
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\mathoff
```

The italic correction is inserted between the “g” and the exponent. The thin space follows.

#### Third case

```
....\mathon
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x12.91669
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.....\kern0.13887
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -3.62892
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 4
....\mathoff
```

The italic correction is inserted between ”g” and the parenthesis. No thin space.

#### Fourth case

```
....\mathon
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x12.91669
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.....\kern0.13887
....\hbox(4.51111+0.0)x4.48613, shifted -4.47224
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/7 4
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
....\mathoff
```

Similar to the third case, with no thin space.

#### Comments

I fail to see excess space in any of these cases.

From a mathematician's standpoint, I believe that cases 2 and 4 should be avoided. Powers of logarithms appear so rarely as not to require a particular notation. It's different with trigonometric functions, where squares and also higher powers appear very frequently. The fourth case would possibly be mistaken for

```
\log(\log(\log(\log x)))
```

Everything applies to `\ln`, but I hate this notation. Mathematicians have commonly used “log” for the only really useful logarithm for a little short of four centuries. Why should engineers and physicists step up and order mathematicians to change their centuries old habits?

If you really want to remove the thin space when subscripts or exponents are present, here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\logop}{\log}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\log}{e{^_}}{%
  \logop
  \IfValueTF{#1}{% there is an exponent
    \IfValueT{#2}{% there is also a base
      _{#2}%
    }%
    ^{#1}\!{}% add an empty atom
  }{% no exponent
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}\!{}}% add an empty atom
  }%
}

\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

$\log x$

$\log(x)$

$\log_{10}x$

$\log_{10}(x)$

$\log^4 x$

$\log^4(x)$

$\log_{10}^4 x$

$\log_{10}^4(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In some areas of math, powers of logarithms are common, and are notated as in cases 2 and 4. You sometimes even get a power of an iterated logarithm, which is notated as $\log^2 \log n$.

Comment: Well, mathematicians owe physicists and engineers many, if not most, of their classical results, so you could argue that it’s the mathematicians who changed the notation, not the physicists or engineers. (I’m a mathematician too, though.)

Comment: @Gaussler That's definitely not the case of the logarithm.

Comment: Perhaps not. But classical mathematics was much more concerned with calculations. When Gauss calculated the position of that comet, I doubt he didn’t apply `log_10` at some point.

Comment: @Gaussler He surely used tables of logarithms and trigonometric functions. They *knew* what logarithm was intended. By the way, it was the planet Ceres (now we'd say planetoid), not a comet.

Comment: I stand corrected. `;-)`

Answer (score 7):

An option that no one has mentioned yet is to write `{\ln^4}`, which gives the operator the spacing of a `\mathord` atom rather than `\mathop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\ln^4 x \\
{\ln^4} x
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]